# How to get Network Adapter's name in android devices

Tags: android, networking

I want to retrieve network adapter's name in android devices.

Comment: What do you mean by network adapter? Can you elaborate it properly?

Comment: On my imagination. LAN Card in android devices? Just kidding! :)

Answer (score 3):

The simpliest way to list all network interfaces in your android device is to execute this command:

```
adb shell ls /sys/class/net
```

Comment: Here is a sample output (I was looking for some and did't find one):
`dummy0 erspan0 eth0 gre0 gretap0 hwsim0 ifb0 ifb1 ip6_vti0 ip6gre0 ip6tnl0 ip_vti0 lo sit0 tunl0 wlan0`